# MemoryError when training a t-sne model

Tags: python, memory, error-handling, jupyter-notebook

## This is my Jupyter code that triggers the MemoryError

```
all_word_vectors_matrix_2d = tsne.fit_transform(all_word_vectors_matrix)
```

### Here is the error

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-c9bac182acc1> in <module>()
----> 1 all_word_vectors_matrix_2d = 
tsne.fit_transform(all_word_vectors_matrix)

C:\Users\Shilpa Suresh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\t_sne.py 
in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    882             Embedding of the training data in low-dimensional space.
    883         """
--> 884         embedding = self._fit(X)
    885         self.embedding_ = embedding
    886         return self.embedding_

 C:\Users\Shilpa Suresh\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\sklearn\manifold\t_sne.py in _fit(self, X, skip_num_points)
    764                 neighbors_nn = neighbors_nn[:, 1:]
    765             P = _joint_probabilities_nn(distances, neighbors_nn,
--> 766                                         self.perplexity, self.verbose)
    767         else:
    768             P = _joint_probabilities(distances, self.perplexity, self.verbose)

C:\Users\Shilpa Suresh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\t_sne.py 
in _joint_probabilities_nn(distances, neighbors, desired_perplexity, verbose)
     93     neighbors = astype(neighbors, np.int64, copy=False)
     94     conditional_P = _utils._binary_search_perplexity(
---> 95         distances, neighbors, desired_perplexity, verbose)
     96     m = "All probabilities should be finite"
     97     assert np.all(np.isfinite(conditional_P)), m

sklearn\manifold\_utils.pyx in 
sklearn.manifold._utils._binary_search_perplexity 
(sklearn\manifold\_utils.c:2683)()

sklearn\manifold\_utils.pyx in 
sklearn.manifold._utils._binary_search_perplexity 
(sklearn\manifold\_utils.c:1697)()

MemoryError:
```

How can I fix this memory error and what does this mean? Please feel free to let me know if you need any more code to understand the error

Update: I just edited my code to split all_word_vectors_matrix into two and then ran the tsne.fit_transform() method on the first half of the all_word_vectors_matrix but that still doesn't seem to solve the issue.

```
all_word_vectors_matrix_list = np.split(all_word_vectors_matrix, indices_or_sections=2)
all_word_vectors_matrix_2d = tsne.fit_transform(all_word_vectors_matrix_list[1])
```

Comment: A memory error simply means that the program ran out of available memory to use when running this code, and looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283220/memory-error-in-python) question it seems that one thing of common advice is to use 64 bit python over 32 bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [memory error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283220/memory-error-in-python)

Comment: I just tried splitting the matrix into two and tried training the first half but the Memory Error is still showing up. Is there a better way to deal with this?