# tensorflow-gpu running for a while has a MemoryError about array

Tags: python, tensorflow

When tensorflow-gpu running for a while(about 2hr~), it has a MemoryError about array

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-680341707274>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/google_sync/google_sync/Programming Language/Tensorflow/game/game.py', wdir='D:/google_sync/google_sync/Programming Language/Tensorflow/game')

  File "C:\Users\wyp87\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\wyp87\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/google_sync/google_sync/Programming Language/Tensorflow/game/game.py", line 210, in <module>
    train_neural_network(input_image)

  File "D:/google_sync/google_sync/Programming Language/Tensorflow/game/game.py", line 193, in train_neural_network
    out_batch = predict_action.eval(feed_dict = {input_image : input_image_data1_batch})

  File "C:\Users\wyp87\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 680, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)

  File "C:\Users\wyp87\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4951, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)

  File "C:\Users\wyp87\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 877, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "C:\Users\wyp87\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1069, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)

  File "C:\Users\wyp87\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 501, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

MemoryError
```

I try :

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

and

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.4)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

BUT, The problem still exists
I  don't know how to solve the error..

[GPU log file:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s9tY4Pbv2Fi5-MeLfCh9vrVYG1OpXH7o/view?usp=sharing)

[My python file:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iDXW69-E5XQZrR6jFzq-C_kPgOHWHBPw/view?usp=sharing)

Computer:MSI GE62 notebook

CPU:I7-6700HQ

GPU:GTX960M

Tensorflow:1.10.0

Python:3.5.6

CUDA9.0

I still have a question
When I use tensorflowGPU, it will crash when the screen recorder app is running, right?

Answer (score 0):

if it would be your GPU-memory giving the error you would see resource exhausted, this seems to be a python error, instead of tensorflow specific. It's your memory getting filled most likely due to inefficient code. See [this questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283220/memory-error-in-python)n.