# gensim: KeyError: “word 'good' not in vocabulary”

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

I am running the below code, but gensim word2vec is throwing a word not in vocabulary error. Can you let me know the solution?

this is my file(file.txt)

```
'intrepid', 'bumbling', 'duo', 'deliver', 'good', 'one', 'better', 'offering', 'considerable', 'cv', 'freshly', 'qualified', 'private', ..
```

this is my code

```
 import gensim 
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as myfile:
      data = myfile.read()



    model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(data,min_count=1,size=32)
    w1 = "good"
    model.wv.most_similar (positive=w1)
```

Output:

```
KeyError: "word 'good' not in vocabulary"


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-22572d5a8082> in <module>()
      7 model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(data,min_count=1,size=32)
      8 w1 = "good"
----> 9 model.wv.most_similar (positive=w1)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py in most_similar(self, positive, negative, topn, restrict_vocab, indexer)
    529                 mean.append(weight * word)
    530             else:
--> 531                 mean.append(weight * self.word_vec(word, use_norm=True))
    532                 if word in self.vocab:
    533                     all_words.add(self.vocab[word].index)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py in word_vec(self, word, use_norm)
    450             return result
    451         else:
--> 452             raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)
    453 
    454     def get_vector(self, word):

KeyError: "word 'good' not in vocabulary"
```

​

Comment: The entire file.txt is in the form of string in **data** variable.

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: please someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import gensim
data=[]
with open('lastlast.txt', 'r') as myfile:
  raw_data = myfile.read()
  raw_data=raw_data.replace('\n',',')
  split_data=raw_data.split(',')
  data=[i.replace("\'",'').replace(' ','') for i in split_data if i!=""]
```

The first parameter should be iterable. Since data is just iterable of sentences it takes every character, but [data] takes every word.
From the docs

```
>>> model = gensim.models.Word2Vec([data],min_count=1,size=32)
>>> model = Word2Vec.load("word2vec.model")
>>> model.train([["hello", "world"]], total_examples=1, epochs=1)
```

Your solution:-
Now if you do this you will get the answer.

```
>>>model.most_similar(['good'])
```

Comment: just there is a problem my file is 150 mg but it just returns one line of it not whole file.what should i do?

Comment: 150mg.it just store little part of it in data variable.

Comment: this is the file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z7a54zSuWo4uZhn_PCqDcJseSqNTBY47/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: thank you.would you tell me when print( data)  what is the last token you see?

Comment: this is the problem.the last token is "cox"

Comment: MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

----> 7   data=[i.replace("\'",'').replace(' ','') for i in split_data if i!=""]

<ipython-input-9-c1b75397fc8b> in <listcomp>(.0)
      5   raw_data=raw_data.replace('\n',',')
      6   split_data=raw_data.split(',')
----> 7   data=[i.replace("\'",'').replace(' ','') for i in split_data if i!=""]

MemoryError:

Comment: @aaaa Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283220/memory-error-in-python

Comment: i installed anaconda 64 on win 2008 server 64 bit with 32 gig Ram.but it still give me ram error.does it work on your system?

Comment: @aaaa Hello, In your question you only asked about getting the data from a text file and storing it in a python variable. You didn't specify about the size of the text file. I am suggesting that you should take up this problem and post it as new question.

Comment: thank you. i just wanna know that can you print it or not?

Comment: @aaaa Yes, I can open it and I can load it and print it.