# Gzip unzip from one s3 bucket to another

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multiprocessing, boto3

I have a bunch of gz files in a folder on s3. I'm trying to unzip the files in parallel and dump the unzipped gz content onto another s3 bucket.

I'm trying to use multiprocess in python and here's what I have tried

I Have a worker function as below

```
def worker_function(objnm,source_bucket,source_folder_location,target_bucket,target_folder_location) :
    filename = objnm.split('/')[-1].replace("GZ.001","txt")
    print("target_file :---" + filename)
    target=target_folder_location + filename
    print("file copying to destination :-- " + target)
    boto3.client('s3').upload_fileobj(Fileobj=gzip.GzipFile(None, 'rb', fileobj=BytesIO(client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=key)['Body'].read())), Bucket=target_bucket, Key=target)
```

This function unzips a gz file and writes it to a s3 bucket. And then I have the if block as below

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    client=boto3.client('s3') 

    source_bucket=sys.argv[1]
    source_folder_location=sys.argv[2]
    target_bucket=sys.argv[3]
    target_folder_location=sys.argv[4]

    objlist = client.list_objects(Bucket=source_bucket,Prefix=source_folder_location)['Contents']
    for object_summary in objlist:
        key = object_summary["Key"]
        print(key)

        if (".GZ" in key):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_function, args=(key, source_bucket, source_folder_location, target_bucket, target_folder_location))
            p.start()
```

But if I run this code, I'm getting the below error

```
Process Process-16:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File ".py", line 31, in worker_function
    boto3.client('s3').upload_fileobj(Fileobj=gzip.GzipFile(None, 'rb', fileobj=BytesIO(client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=key)['Body'].read())), Bucket=target_bucket, Key=target)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/response.py", line 78, in read
    chunk = self._raw_stream.read(amt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 503, in read
    data = self._fp.read() if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 472, in read
    s = self._safe_read(self.length)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 627, in _safe_read
    return b"".join(s)
MemoryError
```

I'm trying to understand what this error mean and how I can resolve it. I'm running this on a huge node with 95 cores. Can someone please help me out. Thank you

Comment: `unzip` referes to a zip archive. You have gzip compressed files, that's not the same as a zip archive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [memory error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283220/memory-error-in-python)